# Where do string substition Variables get saved?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've searched for this a lot, but couldn't find an answer.

I'm searching for the exact location of the Config File for the variables you can add in Eclipse at "preferences > Run/Debug > String Substituion".

My idea is to automatically check for several variables that i need for an simulator, and write them directly to the "string substitution"file.

Comment: What variables are you talking about? As it stands I have no idea what you asking about!

Comment: I edit my question hope it's more understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theses variables are accessed using the `IStringVariableManager` interface:

```java
IStringVariableManager manager = VariablesPlugin.getDefault().getStringVariableManager();
```

The variables on the Run/Debug preferences are 'value variables' which you create with:

```java
IValueVariable vv = manager.newValueVariable("name", "description", "value");
```

you must add the created variables to the manager to make them permanent:

```java
manager.addVariables(variables array);
```

The API does not specify where these values are stored. They appear to be stored in the `org.eclipse.core.variables.prefs` file in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory. Changing this file directly will probably not update the list in the variables manager.

Comment: thanks a lot. works not the way i thought, but works!